# Effecting a Label from one Tabitem of a Tabcontrol from a button from another Tabitem of the Same Tabcontrol (using MVVM, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

My Situation:

I'm trying to affect a label from one `TabItem` of a `TabControl` by clicking a `Button` on another `TabItem` of the same `TabControl`.

I'm currently having a hard time figuring out why the property of my `TextBox textBoxTyp` won't change its value even after updating the property. The binding is correct an a button right next to the `TextBox` (on the same `TabItem`) that's bound exactly like the other `Button` from the other `Tabitem, works perfectly fine. I'm using the MVVM pattern and databinding.

**Here the code of the `TabControl` itself**

```
<TabControl Name="TabSpaces"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding TabIndex, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource vm_Für_Typenschild}}"
            Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,-4">

    <TabItem DataContext="{Binding TypneschildVM, Source={StaticResource vm_Für_Typenschild}}"
            FontSize="15" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#401746"
            Header="Datei" Margin="0,0,-60,0">
        <view:DateiV/>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem MouseLeftButtonDown="SelectedTypenschild" Loaded="Typenschild_Loaded"
            FontSize="15" Height="50" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"
            Background="#401746" Header="Typenschild" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC"
            Margin="56,0,-128,0">
        <view:TypenschildVM Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1,0"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**Here the code from the view  of the `TabItem` with the button that should affect the `TextBox`**

```
<Button Command="{Binding ReadXmlAndInsertIntoDialogsIntoTypenSchild_Command, Source={StaticResource vm_Für_Typenschild}}"
        FontSize="25" x:Name="button_Datei_entfernen" Foreground="White"
        Content="Datei entfernen" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="476,468,476,215"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="326" Height="70">
</Button>
```

**Here the code from the functions that should change the property ( `ReadXmlAndInsertIntoDialogsIntoTypenSchild` & `CompareXmlWithJsonAndInsertIntoDialog` )**

```
namespace WPF_App_RFID_SpinOff.ViewModel
{
    public class TypneschildVM : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICommand
    {
        private string CompareXmlWithJsonAndInsertIntoDialog(string XmlFileStringToCheck, string IdFromJsonFile)
        {
            string ValueTopass = "";
            string line = "";
            StringReader StringReaderOfXmlFile = new StringReader(XmlFileStringToCheck);

            while ((line = StringReaderOfXmlFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(IdFromJsonFile) == true)
                {
                    int IndexRightNow = line.IndexOf('V');
                    int IndexWhereValueStart = line.IndexOf('V');
                    int CounterToGetValue = 0;

                    for (CounterToGetValue = IndexWhereValueStart + 1; CounterToGetValue < line.Length; CounterToGetValue++)
                    {
                        if (line[CounterToGetValue] != '"' && line[CounterToGetValue] != '=' && line[CounterToGetValue] != '/' && line[CounterToGetValue] != '>')
                        {
                            ValueTopass += line[CounterToGetValue];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return ValueTopass;
            // Console.WriteLine(TypenschildM_ToUse.Hardwareversion);
        }

        public void ReadXmlAndInsertIntoDialogsIntoTypenSchild(object parameter)
        {
            int OpenBracketCount = 0;

            string IdFromJsonFile = "";
            string StringOfJsonFile = StaticFunc.ProvideJsonFile();
            string StringOfXmlFile = StaticFunc.ProvideXMLFile();
            string StringOfInformationforTypenschildFromXml = GetPartOfXmlFileForTypenSchild(StringOfXmlFile);
            string StringOfInformationforTypenschildFromJson = GetPartOfJsonFileForTypenSchild(StringOfJsonFile);
            string BlockOfDataforCertainValue = " ";

            Console.WriteLine("test");

            foreach (char character in StringOfJsonFile)
            {
                if (character == '{')
                {
                    OpenBracketCount++;
                }

                if (OpenBracketCount >= 1)
                {
                    BlockOfDataforCertainValue += character;

                    if (character == '}')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(BlockOfDataforCertainValue);
                        IdFromJsonFile = lookOutForID(BlockOfDataforCertainValue);

                        PropTest = CompareXmlWithJsonAndInsertIntoDialog(StringOfXmlFile, IdFromJsonFile);
                        OnPropertyChanged("PropTest");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #region ICommandSchnittstelle
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion

        public TypneschildVM()
        {
            TypenschildM TypenschildM_ToUse = TypenschildM.Instance;
            LeseXMLAus = new RelayCommand(ReadXMLFileForTypenschildVM, StaticFunc.enableExecute);

            ReadXmlAndInsertIntoDialogsIntoTypenSchild_Command = new RelayCommand(ReadXmlAndInsertIntoDialogsIntoTypenSchild, StaticFunc.enableExecute);
            startButtoon_Command = new RelayCommand(ReadXmlAndInsertIntoDialogsIntoTypenSchild, StaticFunc.enableExecute);
        }
    }
}
```

**Heres The Binding of my Textbox**

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True"
        Text="{Binding PropTest, Source={StaticResource vm_Für_Typenschild}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        x:Name="textBoxTyp" Height="22" Margin="243,93,133,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFF3F3F3" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

Comment: You aren't calling OnPropertyChanged in your PropTest property, might that be it?

Comment: @T.Schwarz no that wasnt it but thanks for the effort

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try posting an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you'll have a much better chance of getting your questions answered if you make it easy for people.

Comment: The declaration `<TabItem><view:TypenschildVM/></TabItem>` creates an instance of the TypenschildVM class and assigns it to the Content property of the TabItem. This instance is unrelated to any other TypenschildVM object in your application, especially to the resource `vm_Für_Typenschild`. The declaration should not be there.

Comment: As a note, consider using english identifer names. Umlaute in XAML make our brains hurt.

Comment: @Clemens, Thank you very much for your help, could you maybe give me an example how you would approach this problem?

Comment: No, there is not enough information about what you are actually trying to do. You may however want to search StackOverflow for how TabControl (or ItemsControl in general) is used with MVMM. There's certainly a lot to read.